# VPS Server running with pm2 shuts down after 5-6 hours

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, vps, pm2

I have deployed a React+Node application on a vps. I used nginx and pm2.

I started 2 processes for front end and back end in pm2. Both are running perfectly.

But after 5-6 hours, when I try to access the public IP, it returns 502. When I connect to my server and check pm2 status, both processes are active but public IP doesn't work. Then, I have to restart pm2 servers and it is up again for next 5-6 hours.

How do I solve this issue? I want it to run 24/7.

Also, this is my first time deploying on a VPS. I just followed a youtube tutorial for this setup.

Comment: [`pm2 logs`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#displaying-logs) as its crashed will yield why. most likely its something with your code or database pool etc crashing the server part of your app (express, http)..

Comment: Memory leak? If you watch `pm2 monit` while your nodejs server runs, you may see RAM usage growing. If so, read about how to fix memory leaks. The mistake is usually hanging on to a reference to a Javascript object your app no longer needs.

Comment: Logs:
`Stopping app:app-client id:0`
`App [app-client:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]`
`pid=4613 msg=process killed`
`App [app-client:0] starting in -fork mode-`

On running pm2 monit, I found
1. client side server goes up to 431 mb memory usage, then comes down to 300
2. node js is goes upto 140mb and then comes down to 90.

Conclusion
React app is using much higher memory, but I still don't understand why its crashing. My VPS has 2gb RAM, and total memory consumed by my app is around 500mb which is a lot, but still it should not crash. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Try checking the logs generated by your application, there must be some uncaught exception that is causing the app to crash.

Comment: Locally, the app is running fine. I can't find any exceptions that crashes my local server. By the way, is there any way to automatically restart the server in pm2 when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Install npm globally it will work. I was facing this same problem and try everything pm2 startup etc but it stop after 4 5 hours. Then i installed npm globally it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found out this, whenever you update or upgrade your nodejs version in the server you need to run `pm2 startup` and save the process list `pm2 save`. otherwise if your process crashes it won't restart the processes. In my case I had to downgrade nodejs due to a package and server sent 502 after 5-6 hours. and in the logs process were terminating but no restarts were there. Also please check the logs by `pm2 logs --lines=1000` to investigate further. [See this for more info on pm2 startup.](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/)